# Converting exponential to float

Tags: python, floating-point, exponent

This is my code, trying to convert the second field of the line from exponential into float.

```
outputrrd = processrrd.communicate()
(output, error) = outputrrd
output_lines = output.split('\n')
for line in output_lines:
    m = re.search(r"(.*): ", line)
    if m != None:
        felder = line.split(': ')
        epoch =  felder[0].strip(':')
        utc = epoch2normal(epoch).strip("\n")
        #print felder[1]
        data = float(felder[1])
        float_data = data * 10000000
        print float_data
        resultslist.append( utc + ' ' + hostname + ' ' +  float_data)
```

But, the program stops with this error:

```
File "/opt/omd/scripts/python/livestatus/rrdfetch-convert.py", line 156, in <module>
    data = float(felder[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 6,0865000000e-01
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Your float literal contains a comma `","` instead of a decimal point `"."`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easy way is replace! One simple example:

```
value=str('6,0865000000e-01')
value2=value.replace(',', '.')
float(value2)
0.60865000000000002
```

Comment: This does not change anything

Comment: @Zorro try `print( "%.16f" % float('6.4e-05'))`

Comment: thanks working, but what if i need `0.0000640` in float number without exponential and not string

Comment: [site](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python) @Zorro

Answer (score 11):

The reason is the use of comma in `6,0865000000e-01`. This won't work because `float()` is not locale-aware. See [PEP 331](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0331/) for details.

Try [`locale.atof()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.atof), or replace the comma with a dot.

Answer (score 10):

The `float` value is correct; you simply need to display it as desired, e.g.:

```
print(format(the_float, '.8f'))
# print(f'{the_float:.8f}') # For Python >= 3.6
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me, try it out.

```
def remove_exponent(value):
    decial = value.split('e')
    ret_val = format(((float(decial[0]))*(10**int(decial[1]))), '.8f')
    return ret_val
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is useful to you:

```
def remove_exponent(value):
    """
       >>>(Decimal('5E+3'))
       Decimal('5000.00000000')
    """
    decimal_places = 8
    max_digits = 16

    if isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
        context = decimal.getcontext().copy()
        context.prec = max_digits
        return "{0:f}".format(value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(".1") ** decimal_places, context=context))
    else:
        return "%.*f" % (decimal_places, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply by casting string into float:

```
new_val = float('9.81E7')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to convert from string in scientific/exponential notation to a float number (that can result also in exponential notation if too long)

```
num = '-8e-05'

def scientific_to_float(exponential):
  split_word = 'e'
  e_index = exponential.index('e')
  base = float(exponential[:e_index])
  exponent = float(exponential[e_index + 1:])
  float_number = base * (10 ** exponent)
  return float_number

scientific_to_float(num) # return -8e-05 float number
```