# How can i convert exponential values to number by chaining it with df.mean pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a numerical values(float64), I have used the inbuilt (mean,median,mode) function of pandas and chained round function to 4 decimal place, now the result is leading to an exponential value.

```
print(a.mean().round(4))
```

> result = (4.509534e+09)

Is there a way i can chain a inbuild function/some other solution to convert the value to numerical?

I have tried to convert my result to numerical from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195800/converting-exponential-to-float), but it didn't work out.

as Heading specifies i would like a solution for chaining, but **not entering a  suppressing command at top of code** [pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.4f' % x)],

```
a.[pandas mean/median.mode].apply(lambda x: '%.17f' % x).values.tolist()
```

only work for mean and median but not for mode. The solution for above was referred from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [df.style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html). Try:

```
df.style.format('{:.4f}')
```